# Issue with hibernate inheritance subclass not using sequence

Tags: hibernate

Hi My Super class is having Primary key and in my Sub class Entity I want to define/use Sequencer defined in Oracle database but I am always getting value of ID(Primary Key) as 0.It seems sequencer is not getting executed.Please help.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    protected long id;

    @Version
    protected Integer version = Integer.valueOf(0);

    public GenericEntity() {
    }

    public abstract long getId() ;

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Sub Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pf_address")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SEQ_PF_ADDRESS", name = "seq_address", allocationSize=1)
public class Address extends GenericEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5627302335705194341L;
    private String country = "";


    @GeneratedValue(generator= "seq_address", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "ID"))
    public long getId() {
    return id;
    }

        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Super class we only need to use sequence.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "vivas_sequence_generator")
    protected long            id;



    @Version
    protected Integer         version          = Integer.valueOf(0);

    public GenericEntity() {}

    public long getId(  ) {
    return id;  
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
    return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
    this.version = version;
    }
}
```

Sub Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pf_address")
@GenericGenerator(name = "vivas_sequence_generator", strategy = "native", parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "SEQ_PF_ADDRESS"),
        @Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "none") })
public class Address extends GenericEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5627302335705194341L;
    private String            country          = "";



    public String getCountry() {
    return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
    }

}
```

where SEQ_PF_ADDRESS is actual sequence in Oracle database. Similarly for other sub class entities only change will be different sequence name.

For e.g.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pf_stakeholder")
@GenericGenerator(name = "vivas_sequence_generator", strategy = "native", parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "SEQ_PF_STAKEHOLDER"),
        @Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "none") })
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Stakeholder extends GenericEntity {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this

```
@Table(name = "pf_address")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SEQ_PF_ADDRESS", name = "seq_address", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_address", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
```

Comment: I have all these annotations in Sub class code.Please see and help.

Comment: I think you should do in it in order for example **@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SEQ_PF_ADDRESS", name = "seq_address",schema = "your schema" ,allocationSize=1)** with in  the sub class and below it **@GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_address", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)**

Comment: After using your suggestions my Sub class looks like below.But still id is always picking 0(default) value.Please suggest. Sub Class inside code:

Comment: @Override 
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SEQ_PF_STAKEHOLDER", name = "seq_stakeholder",schema="TEST01", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_stakeholder", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
public long getId() {
  return id;
     }
...